# Using a regex to determine domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

If, as here at work, we have test, staging and production environments, such as:

http://test.my-happy-work.com

http://staging.my-happy-work.com

http://www.my-happy-work.com

I am writing some javascript that will redirect the browser to a url such as:

http://[environment].my-happy-work.com/my-happy-video

I need to be able to determine the current environment that we are in.

There is the possibility that I will currently be at a url such as:

http://[environment].my-happy-work.com/my-happy-path/my-happy-resource

I want to be able to grab the window.location but strip it of everything but:

http://[environment].my-happy-work.com

And then append to that string + "/" + "my-happy-video".

I am not skilled with regex, but I suppose there would be a way to parse the window.location up to the ".com"

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just use `window.location.hostname`?  That only contains the domain.

You can combine that with `window.location.protocol` to generate what you need:

```
var domain = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
```

[More on window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

Comment: Yes, then use some regex on the window.location.hostname to determine your subdomain(or environment as you call it), the regex would be something like window.location.hostname.match(/^(.*)\.my-happy-work\.com$/) which will return an array with the captured field(what is enclosed in parenthesis).

Answer (score 3):

This expression should do the trick:

```
^https?://([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9\-]+)\.[a-z]+
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly another option would be to deploy separate code in each environment.  Not totally separate code, but maybe set a variable to "PRODUCTION" when in production, or to "STAGING" when in staging mode.

This decouples the mode your application should run in from the domain name.

Comment: This is sensible. Don't even need to change the code though - just create an ini/config file on each machine that stores the mode (with a safe fallback if no file found).

Comment: (This is assuming you have a server-side script to read such a file and, if necessary, generate the appropriate JS variable.)

Answer (score 0):

I wish to point you to:
[What's a good regular expression to capture the root domain of a given url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910235/whats-a-good-regular-expression-to-capture-the-root-domain-of-a-given-url/1910347#1910347)