# What's a good regular expression to capture the root domain of a given url?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript, how can I capture the string `example.com` from the current domain `http://example.com/bar?param=value` or `https://www.example.com`?

My first attempt doesn't work correctly:

```
https?://w?w?w?[.]?[^?/]
```

Comment: In what language? Many languages have built in tools for parsing URLs, that'd be more suited to the job than a regex.

Comment: (e.g. Python's `urlparse` - http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html)

Comment: **In Javascript:** [http://gunblad3.blogspot.com/2008/05/uri-url-parsing.html](http://gunblad3.blogspot.com/2008/05/uri-url-parsing.html)

Answer (score 16):

You don't need regex for this! Let the browser parse it for you:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://foo.com/bar?param=value';
a.hostname; // "foo.com"
```

Voila!

Comment: but still doesn't extract the root domain

Answer (score 1):

If doing this in JavaScript, you don't even need a regex.  You can use the location object like so:

```
var host = window.location.host;
```

This link has more information about how to get other parts of the URL: http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html.

Answer (score 1):

For full cross-browser compatibility simply go with the document object, not window:

```js
var theHost = document.location.host;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really sold on using regular expressions rather than built-in tools in the language (e.g. PHP's [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function) then something like:

```
(?:(\w+)://)([^/]+)(/\w+)?
```

will do it in a very rough way, with the hostname in subgroup 2. This is just a quick-and-dirty hack though (and won't work in all cases), and I would advise using the language's built-in tools.

If it's Javascript and the current URL, look at `window.location.host` or `window.location.hostname`.